# Move os from a hard drive to another

Tags: installation, ubuntu-14.04, hard-drive

Right now, I have two hard drives on my computer, a 1TB one and another 2TB one... The 1TB one has Ubuntu 14.04 in it and the other has data only. So, right now, my computer boots from the first hard drive but all my data is in the other. Now, I want the 2TB hard drive to have Ubuntu 14.04 or new Ubuntu 16.04 in itself and want to free the 1TB hard drive for other use. What is the easiest way out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say Backup the DATA Files on the 2TB to a 3rd drive, then clone the OS partition from 1TB to 2TB. Finally put back the DATA on the 2TB. Although personality I wouldn't put my OS and DATA on the same drive.

Comment: will it become bootable if I clone a partition from a drive to another?